# find/globbing: what am I doing wrong here?

Tags: regex, shell, wildcard, glob

Hopefully a quick question, I'm annoyed enough that I cannot seem to figure this out myself:

I'm trying to list all Mac libraries that have only the major version in their filename, as in

```
libFoo.X.dylib
```

where X is a decimal (a single digit in my case).

I'm using

```
find /path/to/here -name "lib[^.]*.[0-9].dylib"
```

Thinking that this should give me filenames consisting of
- a part starting with "lib" and no dot
- a single dot
- a single digit
- the .dylib extension

But I also get files of the type `libfoo.0.1.2.dylib` so my assumption must go wrong somewhere.

Comment: `-name`accepts shell globing patterns, not regexp. Use `-regex` instead. And always use `man` pages in Linux, it's the first source for information.

Comment: Erm, I did RTFM before asking here of course (and it should be evident that I'm not doing this on linux!). Are you saying that shell glob[b]ing cannot do what I want?

Comment: @RJVB, ...as implemented by bash, shell globbing is indeed powerful enough to do what you want, as it has optional extglob syntax (with `shopt -s extglob` enabled, `+([^.])` matches one-or-more non-dot things) -- but for `find` you need traditional `fnmatch`-style globbing, which indeed has no "zero-or-more" or "one-or-more" modifier, so you can't say that you want any number of non-dot things in a position; hence the need for proper regular expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this `find` with `-regex` option:

```
find /path/to/here -regex '.*/lib[^.]*\.[0-9]\.dylib'
```

Changes are:

- Use `-regex` option to match a regex
- `.*/` at the start to allow for pathname to be matched before filename
- dot must be escaped in a regex to match literal dot

Comment: Thanks, I think I would have arrived at that formula too ultimately but this saved me quite some time. I think the caret is redundant here, as is (in my case) the `$`.

Comment: You actually don't need the `$` at the end; `-regex` patterns are anchored by default at both ends, which is why you need the `.*` in the front here.

Comment: Now I'm going to need to figure out how to escape that search pattern such that I can include it in a Tcl `exec` expression without getting an error from find (`find: .*/lib[^.]*\.[0-9]\.dylib: unknown primary or operator`)....

Comment: @MarkReed: Thanks so much. I learnt something new: `-regex patterns are anchored by default at both ends`

Comment: @RJVB In Tcl you need to use `{`...`}` instead of single quotes around the argument to `-regex`, but otherwise it should work fine as-is.

Comment: @anubhava yup. If they weren't anchored, you wouldn't need the `.*` in the front; since they are, you don't need the `$` at the back. It would be weird to have them anchored on only one end, which is the only way you'd need both the `.*` and the `$`.

Comment: Yes that's right, use of `.*/` makes it clear that regex is anchored.

Comment: @anubhava: use of `{}` just removes the need for quoting, but I think I need more sleep for once this night ... I'd forgotten to remove the `-name` before the `-regex` argument :-/